# how to setting form display

Tags: css

i have a form input..i've been made it using jquery...
i want my form show not too long..but actually it need to scroll the page in monitor..

how could i setting my form eventhought i have much item for input data??
i want my form show in one page (no need use scroll bar)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure that the height of the page does not exceed the standard size. 
Or you can use an Iframe inside a DIV.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
                body
                {
                        font-family:Times new roman, verdana;
                        font-size:22px;
                        width: 850px;
                        margin-left: auto;
                        margin-right: auto;
                        margin-top: 6px;
                        background-image:url("wood_texture2.jpg");
                }
        </style>

is that too big?

Comment: What is your HTML content like? The above CSS only shows that you are setting width and not height, so definitely you will get a scroll bar if you have more form controls and the body content. Or you meant to say that you have a horizontal scroll bar? if thats the case , you will have to layout your form controls accordingly or consider using an Iframe. Refer www.w3schools.com for DIV and Iframe.